# Migrating an .sql database to WordPress

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, database-migration

I have an SQL file for a database from an old custom blog CMS. I am trying to import the articles into WordPress but I am now stuck. So far, I have managed to isolate the table structures for the CMS (see below). I have also identified the columns that i need. These are (Post, Title, Date, Image, Category). Now I have to map these columns to some columns in the Wordpress schema somehow and that is where I am getting stuck.

Here is the SQL structure of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads_ng_ads` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ad_type` enum('media','text','html') character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `media_type` enum('image','flash','other') character set latin1 collate latin1_bin default NULL,
  `media_width` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `media_height` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `media_size` int(6) default NULL,
  `media_path` varchar(128) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin default NULL,
  `uri` varchar(128) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `is_hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `geo_target` int(11) default NULL,
  `alternative` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `zone_target` text character set ascii collate ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `uri_target` text character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `zone_target` (`is_hidden`,`active_from`,`active_to`,`geo_target`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=757 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `ads_ng_statistics` (
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `clicks` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ad_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `restricted` tinyint(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=253 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `featured_column` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL default '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `body_html` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `in_homepage` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `img_title` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `meta_t` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_k` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_d` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `public` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1381 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Just wanna say good luck my friend

Comment: You can check this answer for your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49202/importing-a-database-from-a-custom-built-cms-to-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the latest WordPress version(4.9.1), you just need to create a script that will import all data to table wp_posts for example if you want to import as WordPress posts. Example: "Title" to "post_title", "post" to "post_content", etc.
[image: WordPress wp_posts table]